# Django: Проверить есть ли значение среди ключей choices

Tags: python, django

Есть такой список разрешённых значений

```
choices_vars = (
    ('key1', 'val1'),
    ('key2', 'val2'),
    ('key3', 'val3')
)
```

Как проверить, что полученный от пользователя ключ user_key есть среди ключей key1,key2,key3?
Могу перебрать массив, и проверить каждый ключ, но наверняка есть уже какое-то хорошее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить список n-ных элементов каждого подсписка при помощи конструкции:

```
list(zip(*choices_vars))[n]
# для n=0 вернёт ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')
# для n=1 вернёт ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
# и т.д.
```

Ну а дальше банальный `if` ... `in` ...:

```
if 'key2' in list(zip(*choices_vars))[0]: 
    ...
if user_key in list(zip(*choices_vars))[1]:
    ...
```

Хотя я не очень понял, что такое user_key и в каких значениях вы собрались его искать. Но, думаю, смысл понятен.

Answer (score 0):

По моему можно проще:

```py
choices_vars = (
    ('key1', 'val1'),
    ('key2', 'val2'),
    ('key3', 'val3')
)
# функция для проверки возвращет только True при совпадении
def check(key, vars):       
  for i in vars:
    if key in i: return True
```

Ну, а теперь проверим:

```py
>>> check("key1", choices_vars)
True
>>> check("key", choices_vars) # ничего не происходит
```

Перечитал еще раз вопрос и могу предположить, что значения `key`  скорей всего уникальны. Это так? Если мое предположение верно, тогда лучше использовать словарь. Наподобие такого:

```py
choices_vars = {'key1': 'val1',
     'key2': 'val2',
     'key3':'val3'}
```

смысл - это хранение уникальных значений ключей. А, поиск по ключам примерно также:

```py
>>> "key1" in choices_vars.keys() 
True
```